# Taylor expansion of $\frac {1}{|x-y|}$with x and y two vectors

Tags: taylor-expansion, vector-analysis, electromagnetism

This equation comes from a physics script on electrodynamics, saying that this equation comes from a Taylor series expansion. [image]

I understand the first equality, but not the second one. It is really not clear for me how the second equality relates to Taylor series.

I try to make sense out of this but I'm stuck. I saw [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1755270/taylor-expansion-of-frac1-x-y) exactly about this problem, but there is no explanation on how we find this Taylor expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{x}$, then
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+x^2-2\vec{r}\cdot\vec{x}}} =
(r^2+x^2-2rx\cos\theta)^{-1/2}
=\frac{1}{r}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{r^2} - 2\frac{x}{r}\cos\theta \right)^{-1/2}
$$
Use the Taylor series $(1+z)^{-1/2} = 1 -\frac{1}{2}z + O(z^2)$ as $z \to 0$.
Then as ${x/r} \to 0$ we get
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+x^2-2\vec{r}\cdot\vec{x}}} =
\frac{1}{r}\left(1 - \frac{1}{2}\left(- 2\frac{x}{r}\cos\theta\right)
+O\left(\frac{x^2}{r^2}\right)\right)
=
\frac{1}{r} + \frac{x}{r^2}\cos\theta
+O\left(\frac{x^2}{r^3}\right)
\\=
\frac{1}{r} + \frac{\vec{x}\cdot\vec{r}}{r^3}
+O\left(\frac{x^2}{r^3}\right)
$$

---

The OP did not say whether $x/r \to 0$ or $x/r \to \infty$.  But if $\infty$, then we get a different answer, so it must mean $0$.

Comment: Thank you! it was easier than what I expected